# Get link anchor out of url with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a link like

```
<a href="example.com#exampleId>Link</a>
```

I need to get the value "#exampleId" into a var. How can i do that? I just found solutions without the #.

Thanks for your help and best regards

Comment: When do you need to get that, on an event, page load?

Comment: A click event. On page load i can do it with window.location.hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is good trick to get anchor link parts in object, please try this code

```
<a href="example.com#exampleId">Link</a>

<script>
var parse  = document.createElement('a');
parse.href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
alert(parse.hash);
</script>
```

## DEMO

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").click( function(){
    console.log(this.hash);  // => #exampleId
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzueauqh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var link = $("a").attr('href');
    alert(link.substr(link.indexOf('#')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an anchor element:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = $('a').attr('href');
console.log(url.hash);
```